# apt-get broken, cannot fix or remove libapt-pkg4.12

Tags: apt, 64-bit, kubuntu

I managed to break my package management.
If I try to make an upgrade, I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapt-pkg4.12 : Breaks: libapt-pkg4.12:i386 (!= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.3) but 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2 is installed
 libapt-pkg4.12:i386 : Breaks: libapt-pkg4.12 (!= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2) but 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then I try to follow apt-get recommendation:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libapt-inst1.4:i386 libapt-pkg4.12:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
48 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 3 866 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
E: Internal Error, No file name for libapt-pkg4.12
```

Kubuntu 12.04 64bit. Can anyone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

and try again.

You can also download the `libapt-pkg` package from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/libapt-pkg4.12) and install it manually:

---

**If the above commands don't work:**

**Update:** The command below doesn't work. Download the appropriate version directly at http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/.

Download the package using the following command:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Now remove the currently installed package:

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -r libapt-pkg4.12
sudo dpkg --force-depends -r libapt-pkg4.12:i386
```

Then, install the downloaded package:

```
sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Run, the following command again and check:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Did that. It finished upgrade, but I still get this when I try to upgrade:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapt-pkg4.12 : Breaks: libapt-pkg4.12:i386 (!= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.3) but 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2 is installed
 libapt-pkg4.12:i386 : Breaks: libapt-pkg4.12 (!= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2) but 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.3 is installed`

Comment: try the updated answer.

Comment: thanks, it works now. I had to remove libapt-pkg4.12:i386 too. Linux package management can cause a lot of headaches.

Comment: For `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb` I get the error: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-10-06 22:04:10 ERROR 404: Not Found.
`. Gulp.

Comment: look for appropriate version at http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/.

Comment: @Mochan : try this, it'll work  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.5ubuntu2_amd64.deb

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did it:

First, I downloaded this 2 deb files:

```
apt_0.9.7.7ubuntu3_i386.deb
libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.7ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

Second, I run this command:

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -r libapt-pkg4.12
```

Then I install the 2 deb files with this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i apt_0.9.7.7ubuntu3_i386.deb libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.7ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

and it works....

Answer (score 0):

I had the dependency apt, apt-get, apt-key error on my debian stretch and after thousands of browser tabs, reboots and program crashes, I solved it by purging the apt version I had and re-downloading and installing the latest apt [here](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/apt/download) and got => (apt_1.8.0_alpha2_amd64.deb) which solved my problems. from (manual) download folder, run`dpkg -i apt_1.8.0_alpha2_amd64.deb` as root.