# sudo apt-get Does not work (ubuntu gnome)

Tags: apt, gnome, update-manager

Lately I was not able to perform sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get install, etc.
Every time I'm typing sudo apt-get install PROGRAM_NAME I get

```
Reading packages list..
```

For a a brief moment and then I only see is:

```
 user_name@laptop_name:~$ .. 1%
```

I also used to get force close error every time performing

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But I checked the ignore this error next time.

I tried removing all my ppas from the software & updates app but it didn't help.

Please help.

Using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Have you checked the main, universe, restricted, and multiverse checkboxes in  Settings -> Software & Updates -> Ubuntu Software ?

Comment: Yes I have
Still no good

Comment: And after I try to reload it, it gives me an error
"It seems that the daemon died."

Comment: Does your Software-Center work? i mean, can you install software through there? If that does work, you could try uninstall and reinstall apt, or replace it with yum package manager. Yum is pretty similar to apt, and is default on Fedora

Comment: I can't even open software center it crushes on start.

How can I uninstall apt?

Comment: And how can I install yum without apt?

Comment: Here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/yum/

Comment: And here for apt : https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/apt/

Comment: Clicking download will send me to the software center which is using apt which is not working

Comment: You can download source package from < packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/apt >  and use dpkg command to install

Comment: Trying to install apt using dpkg getting this error:


dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 (1.0.1ubuntu2.5) breaks apt (<< 0.9.4~) and is installed.
  Version of apt to be configured is 0.7.25.3ubuntu9.17.1.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt

Comment: Refer to this : http://askubuntu.com/a/178890/295286 . There's another answer on the same page,too

Comment: I followed the above instructions and it removed all my apps including the system apps!

Comment: Well, guess I'll reinstall my system.
Fun.

Comment: If I'm already reinstalling UBUNTU, which version do you recommend?

Comment: Probably that's the only solution here so far. Backup the files, and reinstall. Sorry, i couldn't help you. There's other uses here, more advanced than me, so someone might figure this out. As for which version to recommend, 14.04 is Long Term Support, so you'll get newer stuff, plus patches for Shellshock . https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: I can't backup my files cause I don't have the explorer any more neither the backup application..

Comment: You could boot of the live usb , mount the hard drive, and copy the files through there. Or upload them to cloud storage, like Dropbox